# Derivative of $\mbox{sgn}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, step-function

I get a different result than the book I'm reading for the derivative of the sign function.

Let's define the sign function, $x \mapsto \mbox{sgn}(x)$, as

$$ \mbox{sgn} (x) =  \begin{cases} 
      1 & x > 0 \\
     -1 & x < 0 \\
   \end{cases}$$

Let $u(x)$ be the Heaviside step and $\delta(x)$ be the Dirac delta. By definition, $u'(x) = \delta(x)$ and $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$. I can rewrite $\mbox{sgn}(x) = u(t) - u(-t)$. Differentiating, we get

$$\mbox{sgn}'(x) = u'(x) - u'(-x)$$

So far the book and I agree. Here is where we disagree. I then proceed to say

$$\mbox{sgn}'(x) = \delta(x) - \delta(-x) = 0$$

whereas the book says

$$\mbox{sgn}'(x) = \delta(x) - [-\delta(x)] = 2 \delta(t)$$

This implies that $u'(-t) = -\delta(t)$ which I don't agree with.

Comment: This is what happens when you call the Dirac distribution a "function".

Comment: $(u(-x))' = u'(-x)(-x)' = -u(-x)$. You have the wrong sign when you take the derivative of $sgn$.

Comment: There is no problem with the Dirac function here

Comment: @VasilyMitch Yes it is, because the only way you can properly calculate/talk about the derivative of $u(-x)$ is as a distribution.

Comment: Delta function is an element of generalized functions. All rules of differentiation still apply.

Comment: Ugh! I've made such a silly mistake!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you differentiate a complex function, you should multiply by the derivative of the internal function. In other words:
$$
\frac d{dt}u(-t) = u'(-t)\frac{d(-t)}{dt} = -u'(-t)
$$

Answer (score 2):

**There are few issues with your computation**

First, $\delta$ is not a function, it is the distribution
$$
\delta(f)=f(0) \,.
$$
It indeed satisfies
$$
\delta \circ I = \delta
$$
where $I(x)=-x$ is the reflection.

Next, you can indeed write
$$
\mbox{sgn}(x)=u(x)-u(-x) 
$$
[be carefull with the variable]. Note here that by the chain rule
$$
\left( u(-x) \right)'=u'(-x) (-x)'=(\delta \circ I )(-1)=-\delta
$$
This is the part you do not agree with, but this is correct. You forgot to apply the chain rule here.

If you want to see this properly, note that **as a distribution**, the derivative of $u(-t)=u\circ I$ is
$$
(u \circ I)'(f)=(u \circ I)(f') =\int_{\mathbb R} f'(t) u(-t) d t = \int_{-\infty}^0 f'(t) d t = [f(t)]_\infty^0 =f(0)= \delta(f) \,.
$$

Theerfore

$$
\left(\mbox{sgn}(x)\right)'=\delta - (- \delta)=2 \delta  
$$
which is the correct answer.